# Is there a way to activate IE mode in Edge Options?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

[image: Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode]

Hello,

I want to achieve this by having an option inside the EdgeDriver but I cant seem to find it anywhere on the map?

I am trying to open a page in IE mode inside Edge with Selenium and EdgeDriver.

Is there a way to achieve this great thing? [pun intented]

Comment: Do you want to use Edge options itself? Or are you looking for a way to start Edge in IE mode? If so i have posted solution below. It uses ieoptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 questions in this thread.

1. Is there a way to activate IE mode in Edge Options?

There is no way to activate IE mode bypassing the Edge options parameter in the Selenium Edge driver.

2. I am trying to open a page in IE mode inside Edge with Selenium and EdgeDriver. Is there a way to achieve this great thing?

Yes, it is possible to automate the IE mode in the new MS Edge browser using the Selenium web driver.

The new Microsoft Edge allows you to run IE11 validation for legacy sites in addition to your modern experiences. To run your IE11 tests in Microsoft Edge, download the [IEDriverServer](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) from Selenium. Then you must pass in a capability to put Microsoft Edge into IE Mode and then run your tests.

Because this capability puts the whole browser into IE11 Mode, you cannot simultaneously test content that should render in the modern Chromium engine, but you should be able to run all of your IE11 tests and validate the rendering in Microsoft Edge. Note that this code requires an update to IEDriverServer which should be included in the next release of Selenium.

After you download the new IEDriverServer from SeleniumHQ and follow the directions for the “Required Configuration” as documented [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), you can run the following code to launch the new Microsoft Edge in IE11 mode and run some tests:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    var dir = "{FULL_PATH_TO_IEDRIVERSERVER}"; 
    var driver = "IEDriverServer.exe"; 
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir) || !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, driver))) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to find {0} in {1} folder.", dir, driver); 
        return; 
    } 

    var ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(dir, driver); 
    var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions{}; 
    ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgechromium", true); 
    ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", @"\\msedge.exe"); 

    var webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); 
    webdriver.Url = "http://www.example.com"; 
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Notes:**

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of the IE driver server.
2. I suggest making a test with the latest version of the Stable Edge browser.
3. Try to pass the full path of the Edge browser in the 'ie.edgepath' capability. For example:

   ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe");
4. Make sure you close all the already opened instances and tabs of the Edge browser before running the code. Otherwise, it will generate an error.

References:

1. Scroll to the [Automating Internet Explorer mode](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/11/04/edge-chromium-release-candidate-get-ready/) point in this link.
2. [kypflug/webdriver-edge-ie-mode.cs](https://gist.github.com/kypflug/4e8291e6ee65929944f8ba74b1575dd8#file-webdriver-edge-ie-mode-cs)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did exactly as you put and changed the path for ie driver server and msedge and I always get this exception> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:53428/session timed out after 30 seconds.'

Comment: I also got this now> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. CreateProcess() failed for edge with the following command: \\msedge.exe --ie-mode-force --internet-explorer-integration=iemode http://localhost:54387/ (SessionNotCreated)'

Comment: Please check the notes in my modified answer. It can help you to fix the issue. Let us know whether it works for you or not.

Comment: This worked for me but. i wanted to make it headless aswell and how will i do it? Does Edge in IE Mode support headless mode?

Comment: Running the Edge chromium-browser in IE mode will put the whole browser in an IE mode. Headless execution is not supported by the IE browser. so it will also not work when you try to automate the Edge chromium-browser in an IE mode.

Comment: Yes it worked, sorry for the delay answering. However, running in edge with IE mode, I was not able to jump to another window with selenium. I was hoping to have it run in headless mode too, but I now see its not possible. Its a shame companies still use IE for older Portals. Thanks for claryfing things @Deepak-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Below code (which is in VB.NET, but you can easily modify it to C#) will start Chromium Edge in IE Mode

```
 Dim ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService("DIRECTORY_PATH_HAVING_IEDriverServer.exe", "IEDriverServer.exe")
 Dim ieOptions = New InternetExplorerOptions
 ieOptions.IgnoreZoomLevel = True
 ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgechromium", True)
 ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe")
 Dim driver = New InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com")
```

You can download IEDriverServer from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/