# Disable/Remove Browser's Infobars while in IE mode in Chromium Edge Browser in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

How can I get rid of 2 infobars which appear when I'm running a Selenium automated testing in IE mode in Chromium Edge Browser?

I followed closely the instructions on how to run tests in IE mode in Chromium Edge Browser here and it works great:
[Is there a way to activate IE mode in Edge Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361687/is-there-a-way-to-activate-ie-mode-in-edge-options)

However, when I start the test, 2 infobars appear and a "Microsoft Edge Closed Unexpectedly" popup which I can't remove.

The problem is I don't create an Edge Driver rather an IE Driver so I can't send any instructions to the Edge.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent these infobars using the Registry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the "Restore Pages" Alert, go to:

for Edge
C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default

for Chrome:
C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

And open the file: Preferences
Change the "exit_type" to "Normal" and the browser will open without the Alert

You can also sets the file as a Read Only file which will prevent further changes