# Is there a way to automate IE Mode in Microsoft Edge browser for project in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Refers to this thread : [Is there a way to activate IE mode in Edge Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361687/is-there-a-way-to-activate-ie-mode-in-edge-options)

It may sound like a duplicate, but my question is not if automating IE Mode in Edge is possible or not, but if it is possible for Ruby. So far, I only saw the code that can run Edge in IE mode in C#, VB.NET, etc but not in Ruby.

Here is the code I refer to :

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    var dir = "{FULL_PATH_TO_IEDRIVERSERVER}"; 
    var driver = "IEDriverServer.exe"; 
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir) || !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, driver))) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to find {0} in {1} folder.", dir, driver); 
        return; 
    } 

var ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(dir, driver); 
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions{}; 
ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgechromium", true); 
ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("ie.edgepath", @"\\msedge.exe"); 

var webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, ieOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); 
webdriver.Url = "http://www.example.com"; 
}
```

If Ruby supports these features, please let me know or share where I can go to look for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find related information about using Ruby to automate Edge IE mode. AFAIK, it only works with **C#**, **VB.NET** and **Python** now.

You can have a try to set the same IE capabilities in Ruby, if it doesn't work, then I think Ruby doesn't support the capabilities either. In this situation, you can raise a new issue about adding these features in IE WebDriver on [Selenium GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) as IE WebDriver is [maintained by Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/browsers/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using selenium 3, add those 2 new capabilities into the desired capabilities payload

If you're using selenium 4, add those 2 new capabilities to the **first** part of the capabilities array.

The names look W3C-like, so in theory they "should" just work. But I've never heard of anyone even wanting to automate this (i.e. what is the real world use case)