# How to code MS Edge IE Mode on VBA using SeleniumBasic

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Basic to automate MS Edge.

I would like to be able to open a url on MS Edge using IE Mode. I found that there is an IEDriverServer.exe that we can use to run urls on MS Edge IE Mode but there is no example how to use it on VBA.

Can someone help me how to properly put it in my code?

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Set driver = New EdgeDriver

driver.Get ("https://google.com")

driver.Refresh
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the source from where you have downloaded selenium basic exe? also do you want to run them on IE or edge?

Comment: I want to run MS Edge and use MS Edge's Internet Explorer Mode. Here is the link for seleniumbasic: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0

Here is the link to download IEDriverServer:  https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Here is where I learned about IEDriverServer.exe so IE Mode on MS Edge can be automated. But it's only good for C#. link: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/11/04/edge-chromium-release-candidate-get-ready/

Comment: Confirm me you are referring section `Automating Internet Explorer mode` from that blog

Comment: Yes. IE Mode on Edge. But the sample automation is for C#

Comment: I am trying to find a solution but I guess it is not possible with VBA. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587273/7731623

Comment: It said there it worked on VB.Net, any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0

Once you install Selenium Basic exe on your machine, you will get lot of ready examples with vbscript at installation location.

Also make sure to download latest edge driver and put in installation location by renaming as previous.

Sample code

```
Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.EdgeDriver")
driver.Get "edge://settings/defaultBrowser"
driver.Window.Maximize
driver.FindElementByXPath(....<add xpath here>...)
' add required UI component action & xpath for the same.
driver.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Nazneen. I checked this I seem to be having an issue how to proceed. What your sample code does is it will open microsoft edge on the setting to allow Internet Explorer Mode. Once I chose it, I have to open the URL on the new tab. but how do you open a new tab on an  already open Microsoft Edge Instance through VBA?

Comment: That's tricky part :) not sure on this .